# Firebird and Birt: allowing string or number as a parameter?

Tags: firebird, birt

My report accepts one of two values:

1. Either the string "*" which indicates ALL, or
2. An integer indicating the person's ID

So, basically, I have the query:

```
SELECT * FROM people where personid = ?
```

The report runs perfectly if I pass in an integer, but it breaks if I pass in a * indicating all. Also, the query doesn't make sense if I leave it as is and pass in a string. I.e. This works:

```
SELECT * FROM people where personid = 5
```

But this doesn't:

```
SELECT * FROM people where personid = *
```

1. How can I rewrite this so that it will return "all" if the parameter passed in? I.e. It can ignore the where clause completely if the value is *, but it must do the where if the value is an integer.

Currently, if get the error:

I can change the * to rather be a -1. So an alternative is to rewrite the sql so it ignores the constraint if -1 is passed in. SOmething like this:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE (param = -1 OR (param != -1 AND personid = param) )
```

.. but this doesn't seem to work?

Comment: SQL seems to be ok.    Maybe it's because the missing : from params like this:    SELECT * FROM people WHERE (:param = -1 OR (:param != -1 AND personid = :param) )

Comment: `WHERE personid = *` is invalid in any SQL dialect I know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in two parameters (which can have the same value, except when you want to use `*`, as that isn't a valid integer value) and use the condition:

```
SELECT * FROM people where CAST(? AS VARCHAR(20)) = '*' OR personid = ?
```

The first decides whether to select everything (if the value is *), or a specific person (if the value is anything else). As Firebird only supports positional parameters, you need to use two parameters, but you can give them the same value (only when the value is a number, when you use `*`, then the other parameter should simply be a number). Note that the cast is necessary to ensure that Firebird interprets the parameter correctly.

If this gets too slow (because the optimizer might not like this), you should consider using a `UNION`:

```
SELECT * FROM people where personid = ?
UNION
SELECT * FROM people where CAST(? AS VARCHAR(20)) = '*'
```

Answer (score 0):

I use different technique

```
String q="SELECT * FROM people where 1=1";
if PersonId>0 {
  q=q+" and personid="+PersonId.toString();
}
```

Comment: Note that this technique opens up the query to the risk of a SQL injection attack - eg. http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0):

What about this

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE (personid = param OR ( param = -1  ))
```

Answer (score 0):

When I am passing a wild card to SQL in BIRT I use % and don't have a problem

First check if it is a Valid Wild card in your query

If this works

```
 SELECT * FROM people where personid = %
```

Then use

```
 SELECT * FROM people where personid = ?
```

And

If you are using a text box for your user parameter interface set the defualt to %

Else

Set your 'All' value to %